# How to make use of latest QProcess::startDetached function with argument when starting external apps?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, raspberry-pi

when using QProcess::startDetached() on a RasPi in root mode, which i have to, because if wiringPi:

```
QProcess::startDetached("dbus-launch gnome-terminal -- bash -c "sleep 2s;cat "+LogFile+"; exec bash -i"");
```

or

```
QProcess::startDetached("sudo chmod -R 777 "+dir_pizung_sensors.absolutePath());
```

i get the warning:
warning: ‘static bool QProcess::startDetached(const QString&)’ is deprecated: Use
QProcess::startDetached(const QString &program, const QStringList &arguments) instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

Problem:
When using the latest function, like beneath, the external apps won't start silenty with no error at all:

```
QProcess::startDetached("dbus-launch gnome-terminal";{"-- bash -c "sleep 2s;cat "+LogFile+"; exec bash -i""});
```

or

```
QProcess::startDetached("sudo chmod";{"-R 777 "+dir_pizung_sensors.absolutePath()"});
```

don't work.

I use the workaround:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
qWarning() << "Using deprecated-declaration QProcess::startDetached(), because no other way!";
QProcess::startDetached("dbus-launch gnome-terminal -- bash -c "sleep 2s;cat "+LogFile+"; exec bash -i"");
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

I know that:
QProcess::startDetached(const QString &program, const QStringList &arguments)
works for apps with easier argument with no problem on my RasPi4 under Qt.

Can someone please give me a hint ?

/Ralf

Comment: Sorry for my bad typing the inner ";" should be a ",".

Comment: Got some help allready: [link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/140678/how-to-make-use-of-latest-qprocess-startdetached-function-with-argument-when-starting-external-apps)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you're trying to do -- a [mcve] would be even better.  As it stands all of the code/strings shown appear to be syntactically invalid.